# Certain keyboard keys are Malfunctioning

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

While I press spacebar it gives '-' symbol and the enter key is pressed it does its function but it also prints '.' . Some other key are also performing wrong functions(not all keys). I am using english(us) keyboard layout. I found from the layout that while pressing spacebar it also triggers '5' and '-' on numeric keypad all other malfunctioning keys are triggering certain characters on numeric keypad. But my keyboard doesn't have a numeric keypad. How could I solve this issue? (I am using Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Did you try another keyboard to rule out a hardware problem?

Comment: I didn't try another keyboard. But I used phones keypad to make input(using KDE connect) it worked. Using another keyboard is the only solution?

Comment: I would strongly suggest trying to use another keyboard, it really sounds like a hardware malfunction.